# Decomposes the following linear operator in the direct sum of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let be $T : \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ the linear operator $$ T(at^2 + bt + c) = (2a-b+c)t^2 + (a+c)t + 2c. $$ Write $T$ like a direct sum of operators.

My attempt:

I know that $T = T_1 \oplus T_2$, where $T_1$ is the linear operator restricted to the subspace $Ker$ $T^m$ and $T_2$ is the linear operator restricted to the subspace $Im$ $T^m$ with $m$ being the lowest such that $Ker$ $T$ = $Ker$ $T^m$. Knowing this, I computed $Ker$ $T$ and I found $Ker$ $T$ = $\{ 0 \}$. After, I found the matrix of $T$ in the canonical basis $$ [T]_{can} = \left( \begin{array}{crc} 2 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right). $$

Next, I computed $[T]^2_{can}$ and found $$ [T]^2_{can} = \left( \begin{array}{crc} 3 & 2 & 3\\
2 & -1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right) $$ and $Ker$ $T^2 =\{ 0 \} $, but now I don't know how to find the matrices of $Ker$ $T^2$ and $Im$ $T^2$. How can I find this matrices? In this case, the matrix of $Ker$ $T$ = $ (0) $?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint** We are looking for $T$-*invariant subspaces*. Eigenspaces are such. Find eigenvectors.

Comment: Eigenvectors of $T$ or $T^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Tp = \lambda p$ where $p\ne 0$ then we have the system of equations
\begin{align}
\lambda a &= 2a-b+c\\
\lambda b &= a+c\\
\lambda c &= 2c.
\end{align}
Assuming $c\ne0$ yields $\lambda=2$, from which $b=c$ and hence $a=b$. So the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=2$ is $$\Lambda_2 = \left\{\alpha (t^2 + t + 1) : \alpha\in\mathbb R \right\}. $$

Assuming $a,b\ne0$ and $c=0$ yields $\lambda^2 b-2\lambda b + b=0$, from which $\lambda=1$ and hence $a=b$. So the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is $$\Lambda_1 = \left\{\alpha (t^2 + t):\alpha\in\mathbb R\right\}. $$
Now, the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is less than its algebraic multiplicity, so we need to find a generalized eigenvector. Let $q(t) = t^2+t$. If $(T-I)^2 p = 0$ and $(T-I)p\ne 0$, then as $(T-I)q = 0$, we see that it suffices to solve $(T-I)p = q$. If $p(t)=at^2+bt+c$ then the system of equations is
\begin{align}
a-b+c&=1\\
a-b+c&=1\\
c&=0,
\end{align}
from which $c=0$ and $b=a-1$. Setting $a=1$, we have $q(t)=t^2$ as a generalized eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=1$. So we have the generalized eigenspace
$$\tilde\Lambda_1 = \{\alpha(t^2+t) + \beta t^2:\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\}, $$
and hence $T$ can be written as the direct sum
$$T = \left.T\right|_{\tilde\Lambda_1} \oplus \left.T\right|_{\Lambda_2}. $$

Comment: I don't understand how you found $\Lambda_2$, because I know that $Aut_T (2) = \Lambda_2 = Ker (2I - T)$ and I computed this Eigenspace $\Lambda_2 = \{ \alpha t^2 + \alpha t + \alpha; \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \} $, but I don't understand why there is a $\beta$ in your solution, it's ok that $t^2 + t + 1$ and $1$ are linearly independent, but why $\{ t^2 + t + 1, 1 \}$ is a generator of $\Lambda_2$ and why you put the condition $\alpha\beta = 0$?

Comment: The condition $\alpha\beta=0$ implies that $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$. If $p\in\Lambda_2$ with $\beta=0$, then $p(t) = \alpha(t^2+t+1)$. If $p\in\Lambda_2$ with $\alpha=0$, then $p(t) = \beta$. Just thought it was a clever use of notation :)

Comment: ok, but if $\alpha = 0$, so $p(t) = \beta$, therefore, $T(p(t)) = T(\beta) = \beta t^2 + \beta t + 2 \beta \neq 2 \beta$, so $p(t) \notin \Lambda_2$. I didn't understand why you considered $ \{ t^2 + t + 1, 1 \}$ a generator of $\Lambda_2$.

Comment: Ah, let me correct it then.